# Parallel matrix multiplication in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement matrix multiplication with multiple threads. Everything seems to work correctly, however, it work much slower than the usual algorithm. Here is my code

```java
public class Main {
    private static int nRows = 500; //number of rows and columns in matrices
    private static int[][] matrix1 = new int[nRows][nRows]; //first matrix for multiplication
    private static int[][] matrix2 = new int[nRows][nRows]; //second matrix for multiplication
    private static int[][] result1 = new int[nRows][nRows]; //result from linear matrix multiplication
    private static int[][] result2 = new int[nRows][nRows]; //result from parallel matrix multiplication

    private static Thread[][] pool = new Thread[nRows][nRows]; //array of threads

    //method used for transposing a matrix to get its column easily
    public static int[][] transpose(int[][] matrix) {
        int[][] newMatrix = new int[matrix[0].length][matrix.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                newMatrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
            }
        }
        return newMatrix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initializing input matrices (setting all elements = 1)
        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++) {
                matrix1[i][j] = 1;
                matrix2[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }

        long start;
        long end;

        System.out.println("Linear algorithm");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //linear multiplication algorithm
        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++) {
                int temp = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < nRows; k++) {
                    temp += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                }
                result1[i][j] = temp;
            }
        }

        //show result
//        for(int i=0;i<nRows;i++){
//            for(int j=0;j<nRows;j++){
//                System.out.print(result1[i][j] + " ");
//            }
//            System.out.println();
//        }

        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time with linear algorithm: " + (end - start));

        //--------------------

        System.out.println("Parallel algorithm");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int[][] matrix3 = transpose(matrix2); //get a transpose copy of second matrix

        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++) {
                pool[i][j] = new myThread(matrix1[i], matrix3[j], i, j); //creating a thread for each element
                pool[i][j].start(); //starting a thread
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nRows; j++) {
                try {
                    pool[i][j].join(); //waiting for the thread to finish its job
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        //show the result
//        for(int i=0;i<nRows;i++){
//            for(int j=0;j<nRows;j++){
//                System.out.print(result2[i][j] + " ");
//            }
//            System.out.println();
//        }

        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time with parallel algorithm: " + (end - start));
    }

    //class, where parallel multiplication is implemented
    private static class myThread extends Thread {
        private int[] row = new int[nRows]; //row for multiplication
        private int[] col = new int[nRows]; //column for multiplication
        private int i;  //row index of the element in resulting matrix
        private int j; //column index of the element in resulting matrix

        //constructor
        public myThread(int[] r, int[] c, int i, int j) {
            row = r;
            col = c;
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
        }

        public void run() {
            int temp = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < nRows; k++) {
                temp += row[k] * col[k]; //getting the element by multiplying row and column of two matrices
            }
            result2[i][j] = temp; //writing the resulting element to the resulting matrix
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I create a new thread for each element in the resulting matrix. I than write these threads to an array, start them and, finally, wait for them to finish working. I've seen some realizations, where the whole input matrix (both of them) would be given as parameters to the thread. My task is, however, to come up with an algorithm, where only one row and one column (that are necessary for this particular element) are given.

After measuring the time elapsed I get following results

```
Linear algorithm
Time with linear algorithm: 557
Parallel algorithm
Time with parallel algorithm: 38262
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some observations: 1) it is quite common for parallel operations to actually end up slower because of the overhead required to make parallelism happen in the first place.  2) measuring the performance of anything in Java is much, much more complicated than taking the difference of two calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/869736

Comment: using concurrency is useful for blocking I/O operations (like writing to disk, a call to a DB or a web-service), what you are doing is just multiplications, you have to consider if creating a whole new thread (for a single multiplication) is worth the value

Comment: @AlexAndrade I know this is not very efficient and useful in this case, but it's a university task, so I kinda don't have a choice:)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am just confused because the solutions I've seen so far seem to work correctly, even though there were input matrices as parameters. I thought that my implementation (with only row and column as parameters) would still be better

Comment: You're starting a thread for each element in a 500x500 matrix? So, 25,000 threads? I'm not surprised it's slower. Try it on a machine with 25,000 cores and a terabyte of memory. Or, better, use a thread pool executor with as many threads as you have cores, and provide it with tasks to do the individual multiplications.

Comment: Trying commenting out all the multiplication logic in your parallel implementation and run it again, and you'll notice that the overwhelming majority of the time is just spinning all your threads up.

Comment: It might be even better to have each thread handle, say, one row of the matrix, to cut down on the overhead of starting threads for such small operations.

Comment: @DavidConrad I'll try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've written will work fine on a GPU where the concept of threads is very different and the overhead is basically zero. On CPU-based systems, spawning threads is an exceptionally slow operation and it only makes sense if you can amortise this overhead over **a lot** of computational work.

Here is some general advice that will help you write better parallel algorithms for CPUs:

- With computationally heavy tasks, use as many threads as there are physical execution units (cores). SMT techniques such as HyperThreading do not help much unless there is a lot of memory latency. For small matrices that fit in the L1 and L2 CPU caches, the latency is very low and there is nothing to gain from SMT. When more than one thread share the same core, the OS has to context switch between the two, which adds overhead and may trash the cache.
- Keep parallelisation granularity as coarse as possible so to maximise the work per thread. Instead of having one row x column operation per thread, have each thread operate on contiguous blocks of rows / columns. You can try and only parallelise the outer loop, i.e., only over the rows of the first matrix.
- Keep the number of threads dependent on the hardware properties (number of cores) and independent of the problem size. Spawning a separate thread for each row and column scales the overhead linearly with the problem size, which is really bad from performance point of view.
- Avoid false sharing. This happens when two or more threads running on different cores write to memory locations that fall in the same cache line. When one thread updates the cache of its core, the change propagates and invalidates the caches of the other cores that have the same cache line, forcing them to refetch the data. In your case, 16 consecutive values of `result2` fall in the same cache line (cache lines on x86 and ARM are 64 bytes long, `int` is 4 bytes) and are written by 16 different threads. The use of a temporary summation variable alleviates this problem somehow--it is much more severe when false sharing happens repeatedly in an inner(-most) loop.
- Use thread pools for repeated tasks when the number of work items exceeds the number of threads and each thread will get work multiple times. In your case, you give each thread a single work item, so this is not really pooling.

In summary, start as many threads as physical cores and have them work on big contiguous chunks of the input matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel processing only works well with copious processors. If you don't have sufficient processors to split the work into, and sufficient processors to handle the load, then parallelizing is not going to knock your socks off. Parallelizing may make processing slower.

If you have P processors and 8(P) concurrent requests, then using one thread per request is often more efficient for throughput. The break-even point for decomposition is somewhere just greater than 8(P), depending on the application. The logic here is simple. If you have P processors available and you split your work accordingly but there are hundreds of other tasks ahead of you, then what's the point of splitting? It may be faster to process each request sequentially.

Matrix multiplication is a real memory hog. Without sufficient memory, parallelization may make processing slower.

That said a good way to split and join is too lengthy to duplicate here. I maintain an open-source [divide-and-conquer product](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tymeacdse/) that has matrix multiply as one of its built-in functions. Have a look and do what you may.